# Expose custom entity to views

Tags: views, entities, 8

I've created an entity in a Drupal 8 custom module. Right now it's just an entity with base fields.

I want to expose these base fields to views.

I have the entity appearing on the views wizard page, but when I create the view, there are no base fields available for me to add, and the default field that views puts in there shows up as broken/missing.

I've tried referencing the comments module for examples, and have tried defining various views plugins, but I'm not having much luck.

I have `baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type)` defined in my entity controller. What else is required to expose this entity and its fields to views?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to implement [hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/8) just like in Drupal 7. See [comment.views.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!comment!comment.views.inc/8).

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, it's right...

Comment: Me neither, worked great. Can't believe I missed that file. I was too focused on the new Classes. Thanks!

Comment: @Clive I can only guess. Maybe the fact it didn't have any link to the documentation could be the reason. If that is the case, what the user should have done is adding the links, as I did.

Comment: Yes, this is right now the correct answer. Drupal 8 does not yet contain the 7.x entity.module feature that automatically generates the views data definitions based on the entity schema/field definitions. The issues to add it is https://drupal.org/node/1740492 (and https://drupal.org/node/1792828 is a views/entity meta issue), so follow that if you're interested in it.

Comment: because you need implement \Drupal\views\EntityViewsData and add it in entity aanotation

Answer (score 11):

This is now possible via a class annotation; per the documentation for the hook mentioned in the other answer:

> To provide views data for an entity, instead of implementing this
>   hook, create a class implementing
>   [\Drupal\views\EntityViewsDataInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21EntityViewsDataInterface.php/interface/EntityViewsDataInterface/8) and reference this in the
>   "views" annotation in the entity class. The return value of the
>   getViewsData() method on the interface is the same as this hook.

Comment: This is now the good way to go.

Comment: Directly available if the custom entity is generated with drupal console

Answer (score 3):

You should extend `EntityViewsData` and you'll have the integration of your entity.

Example:

```
use Drupal\views\EntityViewsData;

class CustomEntityViewsData extends EntityViewsData {
  public function getViewsData() {
    $data = parent::getViewsData();
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Drupal Console's Content entity generator it will automatically include Views integration.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Chris. It would be helpful if you enhance your answer with more detailed instructions, or references to documentation.

Comment: As per Patricks example this is automatically generated in `web/modules/custom/<yourmodule>/src/Entity/TeamsEntityViewsData.php` It is then available from the views ui landing page `admin/structure/views`. When you create a new view your new entity should be selectable. Wow this question is old so the goto method might have changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a custom entity with views integration:

```
/**
 * Defines the logbook entity.
 *
 * @ingroup logbook
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "logbook",
 *   label = @Translation("Logbook"),
 *   base_table = "logbook",
 *   data_table = "logbook_field_data",
 *   fieldable = TRUE,
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "owner" = "uid",
 *     "uid" = "uid",
 *   },
 *   handlers = {
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\views\EntityViewsData",
 *     "access" = "Drupal\logbook\LogbookAccessControlHandler",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route="entity.logbook.settings"
 * )
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

you need implement \Drupal\views\EntityViewsData and add it in entity aanotation