# Custom Entity's Custom Fields doesn't show in when trying to Add Field in Views

Tags: views, 8, entities

I've created a custom entity and allowed administrators to add custom fields to this entity using the "Manage Fields" Form; however, the custom fields I add to the entity does not appear in the list that pops up when trying to "Add Fields" in a view.

How does one go about making custom fields appear in the Views?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expose custom entity to views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85705/expose-custom-entity-to-views)

Comment: Hmmm, although I do acknowledge that the two are similar, the Base Fields for my Entity does appear in the Add Fields section of the view my problem is the additional custom fields.

In addition, I've already tried the answer accepted as well as the update answer but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this just today. Turns out you shouldn't set **data_table** in the entity type annotation if **translatable** is FALSE. Otherwise views associates all of the fields with the **data_table**, but **data_table** is never associated with **base_table** due to translations being disabled.

Comment: Thanks! That was a tricky bug to figure out.